# How to create a server in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on chat server so I want to create a server and I have been said to use express and socket.io module. Would someone explain me about these modules and help me making chat server?

Comment: Hi Ankit, welcome to SO. Please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how questions should be asked. Please post some code that you have tried, so that we can help you gurther

Comment: This question is way to broad to be covered here on SO. It sounds like you are just getting started and if so the official site for socket.io might be a better place to start out: http://socket.io/

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for learning how to build Chat applications with Socket.io and NodeJS using Express can be found [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) on Socket.io's official website

Scotch.io also provides a good tutorial on this [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-realtime-room-chat-app-using-node-webkit-socket-io-and-mean)

---

In a chat application, Socket.io provides an abstraction over the HTML5 WebSockets API on the client side, and implements WebSockets on the server side, where your server is running on NodeJS.

---

ExpressJS is a Web Framework built on top of Node, that provides you an easier API for building servers, and dealing with requests.

Comment: please mention me prerequisite needed to start developing chat server.'

Comment: You only need a working laptop :) The steps are described in [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) on the Socket.io tutorial. That should be your starting point